# break label statement inwhile loops java

Tags: java

Hi guys the following program output is not understanding can any body explain

I am break with label statement .here i am using 3 while loops with label break statements.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        int i=10,j=10,k=10;

        //Loop:
        while(i!=0)
        {
            System.out.println("i : "+i);

            iLoop:
            while(j!=0)
            {
                System.out.println(" j : "+j);
                j--;
                //iLoop:
                while(k!=0)
                {
                    System.out.println("  k : "+k);
                    k--;
                    i--;
                    break iLoop;
                    //break jLoop;
                    //break Loop;
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

and output is this

```
 i : 10
     j : 10
      k : 10
    i : 9
     j : 9
      k : 9
    i : 8
     j : 8
      k : 8
```

Comment: What don't you understand?

Comment: Don't use labels but use booleans and add them to the while: `while(i!=0 && !iBreak)`

Comment: when break iLoop executed the control should goto iLoop lable.but the control is going to parent of that loop why

Comment: @srihari `break iLoop` doesn't mean `go to the iLoop label`, it means `break the loop which is labelled iLoop`. And what happens when you break a loop? It jumps to the next thing after the loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have labeled the loop based on `j`, when you call the labeled break statement, it breaks out of that loop and goes to the next iteration of the `i` loop. So, the output makes sense for what you have. If we didn't use the label, and had a normal break statement, you wouldn't see the `i` output every iteration like that. As others have stated, try not to use labels, since, as you've experienced first-hand, they are confusing, hard to read (easy to miss), and can be easily replaced with more straight-forward techniques.

Comment: k.. but it should continue from the start of the label iLoop, right, i mean the value of "i" should not be printed because the label iLoop is down of the print statement in "i" while loop..

Comment: No, a labeled **continue** statement would start from the label iLoop, a labeled **break** skips the rest of code inside of the label

Answer (score 1):

From documentation -

```
An unlabeled break statement terminates the innermost switch, for, while, 
or do-while statement, but a labeled break terminates an 'outer statement'.
```

That means outer while loop will be broken.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/branch.html

But using labels in NOT recommended.